# Search Json Object with "AND", "OR" operators

Tags: javascript, json

I am facing an issue where I need to search a JSON object with conditional Operator string.

JSON Object looks like

```
let Data = [
  {Application: 'APIM', Owner: 'Vande Mataram','Customer Code': 'DJLFKASJF',Environment: 'Dev',OS: 'Linux',Region: 'EU','TEAM ': 'DemoTestCOE'},
  {TEAM: 'BCC'},
  {Team: 'DemoTestCOE','Customer Code': 'DJLFKASJF',Owner: 'Vande Mataram',Environment: 'Prod',Region: 'EU',Application: 'Ui-Path',OS: 'Windows'},
  {Application: 'MGMT','Customer Code': 'DJLFKASJF', os: 'Windows','Owner ': 'Vande Mataram', Region: 'East US 2',Team: 'DemoTestCOE',Environment: 'MGMT'  },
  {Application: 'PIER',Owner: 'Govindarajulu Balaji',OS: 'Windows',Region: 'DemoTestCOE', Environment: 'QA'}  
]
```

and the condition string like below..

```
let condition =
  '"Owner": "Vande Mataram" AND ("Application": "APIM" AND "Customer Code": "DJLFKASJF") OR ("Owner": "Vande Mataram" AND "Customer Code": "DJLFKASJF") OR "Owner": "Vande Mataram"'
```

No luck with the internet... how to implement this and I cannot take this to sql server, as it required to be done in javascript.

I searched in the internet to split the condition string to an array split by operator(AND/OR) and search one by one in the json data object, But the condition string varies for each request. And struggling to implement the operator(AND/OR) properly. I am not sure that's the best idea

I need help how to approach this to satisfy any type of condition provided with multiple and nested brackets.

thanks

Comment: you "just" have to write a syntactic interpreter.

Comment: HI Jojo, can you be more elaborate, any code sample or link that would be more helpfull

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_(computing)

Comment: thanks for your help i ended up using alasql.js

Answer (score 1):

`Data` is just an array of objects, so you can use [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

```js
let Data = [
  {Application: 'APIM', Owner: 'Vande Mataram','Customer Code': 'DJLFKASJF',Environment: 'Dev',OS: 'Linux',Region: 'EU','TEAM ': 'DemoTestCOE'},
  {TEAM: 'BCC'},
  {Team: 'DemoTestCOE','Customer Code': 'DJLFKASJF',Owner: 'Vande Mataram',Environment: 'Prod',Region: 'EU',Application: 'Ui-Path',OS: 'Windows'},
  {Application: 'MGMT','Customer Code': 'DJLFKASJF', os: 'Windows','Owner ': 'Vande Mataram', Region: 'East US 2',Team: 'DemoTestCOE',Environment: 'MGMT'  },
  {Application: 'PIER',Owner: 'Govindarajulu Balaji',OS: 'Windows',Region: 'DemoTestCOE', Environment: 'QA'}  
]
// and the condition string like below..
/*
let condition =
  '"Owner": "Vande Mataram" AND ("Application": "APIM" AND "Customer Code": "DJLFKASJF") OR ("Owner": "Vande Mataram" AND "Customer Code": "DJLFKASJF") OR "Owner": "Vande Mataram"'
*/
console.log(Data.filter(item => {
    return item.Owner === 'Vande Mataram' 
    && (item.Application === "APIM" && item['Customer Code'] === "DJLFKASJF") 
    || (item.Owner === 'Vande Mataram' && item['Customer Code'] === "DJLFKASJF")
    || item.Owner === 'Vande Mataram';
}));
```

Comment: Hi chiliNut.. Thank you your response... I need more help.... i receive "condition" is a string with AND OR operators which will be different with different formats for each request... How i can add its as filter... I can format that condition as you mentioned.... But i need to pass that string to filter..